# What does 4мо mean?

Tags: значения

The title says it all. Some guy wrote it on my profile after a game of Dota and I have no clue what 4мо means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Beware that we can use 4 instead of ч. Чмо is an abusive slangish word. 
[image]

Comment: Alright - so it's like an offense but it actually means something like jewelery? Guess the offense doesn't translate that well to english :D

Comment: It's possible that "the guy" did not even used 4. People not-familiar with Cyrillic leters tend to read Ч as 4, З as 3, б as 6 and so on (not counting that in many fonts these symbols are really completely or almost identical). This often leads to questions like "Why so many Russian words look like hacker nicknames?" :)

Comment: @Kazoooka Hmm, what "English" has "schmuck" *meaning something like jewelery*?

Comment: любопытный перевод словом **schmuck**, не от него ли происходит? потому что на идиш оно произносится **шмок**

Comment: I disagree with translation "чмо - schmoe". "Schmuck" is better, but Russian "чмо" is definitely more offensive.

Comment: @Kazoooka Probably you confused the English "schmuck" with the German "Schmuck" :)

Comment: -1 for posting an image where text would be more appropriate.

Comment: @mustaccio, nice of you to sign your -1.

Comment: Well true, in German the word "Schmuck" means Jewelry in English. But I really don't know what the English word "schmuck" means... Is it something like "shmok"?

Answer (score 2):

Это оскорбление!  Если парень написал в вашем профиле "4мо" значит вы его выиграли и он обиделся или в с ним играли в команде, но при этом из-за ваших ошибок проиграли.
Также, применение оскорблений может быть запрещено на том сайте и использовав "4" вместо буквы "ч" тот парень сделал это специально/умышленно, чтобы не заблокировали сообщение